# Python - using .isin() in pandas with the negator ~

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset

**Edit:** Figured it out. Thanks.

I think I must have missed something in my studies and I'm hoping you can help explain.  I'm working on a case study and the following line is used to subset the semi-cleaned df to remove the values in the nonBoroughs list from the column London_Boroughs.

```
NaNFreeDF2[~NaNFreeDF2.London_Borough.isin(nonBoroughs)]
```

The two things I'm not understanding are:

1. Why is it '~' instead of '!' for the not operator? or is '~' an entirely different operator in pandas?
2. Why is the above code used instead of `NaNFreeDF2[NaNFreeDF2['London_Borough'] != nonBoroughs]]` ? Is the above just a more advanced way of doing it that I haven't learned yet?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: pandas and numpy overload the bitwise logical operators rather than the boolean operators. So you use `~` for the same reason you use `&` and `|`.

Comment: It seems that you should take this course and ask the instructor of the course this question.

Comment: Python doesn't have a `!` operator; the logical not operator is the keyword `not`. `!` only appears as part of `!=`.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar I hadn't seen ~ before or forgot it. You helped me logic through it. I appreciate the help.